# Any module or way to add line item in existing order?

Tags: 7, commerce

Is there any way so that admin or whoever permission can add the line item in existing order while editing the order?

Any module or custom code?

Answer (score 1):

It's available out of the box from commerce module...

See screenshot below of Edit Order

[image]

Comment: Yes, There was a configuration mismatch. I changed the setting in store->configuration->managefield->line item.